# mod_rewrite url from php variable

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having this issue which I can't figure out, I'd like to use mod_rewrite to do the following:

```
http://localhost/The+Beatles
```

into

```
http://localhost/artist.php?a=The+Beatles
```

I've tried following some examples on here and other sites and tayloring it to my needs I'm come up with the following but it's not working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) artist.php?a=$1
```

It seems to set the a variable to artist.php which I can't seem to figure out? Hope someone can help.

Dave

Comment: What is it that's not working exactly?

Comment: It's not resolving the url i've tried RewriteRule ^([a-z]/+)/?$ artist.php?a=$1 which will work if it's a single string I think it has a problem with the + maybe in between the words?

Comment: (1) I would better say `RewriteRule ^(.*) artist.php?a=$1 [L]` (2) `mod_rewrite` is usually not easy to setup correctly from fist go, so use `RewriteLog /tmp/rewrite.log` + `RewriteLogLevel 2` so see what's going on. (3) If that does not help, tell us do you put the rules to server config or to `.htaccess`?

Comment: thanks for your help dma_k Phil fixed below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this set of rules (adapted from a vanilla Zend Framework project)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ artist.php?a=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will rewrite requests for non-existent files to your `artists.php` script whilst leaving normal requests for images, stylesheets, JavaScript, etc alone.

In your `artist.php` script, you simply access the original request via the `$_GET['a']` variable.

Comment: Hey Phill, tried this however I couldn't get it to work without 500 itnernal errors, removed everything but the last line and the [L, QSA] and it works and displays my page but it says $_GET['a'] = artist.php ?? not sure whats going on here :( thanks for your time

Comment: logs show [Thu Aug 18 23:48:34 2011] [alert] [client localhost] /var/www/.htaccess: RewriteLog not allowed here

Comment: @Dave What did it say before you added `RewriteLog`? Was it still erroring? FYI, [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) is only allowed in server or virtualhost contexts

Comment: Got it! with the above code you gave me I get this : [Thu Aug 18 23:57:01 2011] [alert] [client localhost] /var/www/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: @Dave Try removing the space between `L,` and `QSA` (updated my answer)

Comment: @Dave Sorry about that. Will have to remember that rewrite flag delimiters must *only* be commas